# Checking if a PHP class has already been called

Tags: php, class

I want to run a template engine on the same file as the file I need it to run on, so I have the template engine that makes things such as {username} turn into a PHP variable in the HTML, be on the same page as everything that handles that. But if I try to do that, I get a class has already been called error, I have tried fixing this error, but this is the closest I have gotten, is there anyway to fix this error? Here is my code:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(0);

if(in_array('NewTemplateHandler', get_declared_classes()))
{

    $template = new NewTemplateHandler("test4.php");
    $template->output();
    //echo "Template has not been called";

}else
{

    echo "Else called";

}

class NewTemplateHandler
{

    protected $file;
    protected $values = array();

    public function __construct($file)
    {

        //$_GLOBALS["ran"] = true;
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->__set("test", "Template Working");
        echo "Template Class Called.";

    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {

        $this->values[$key] = $value;
        echo "$key set as $value<br />";

    }

    public function output()
    {

        if(!file_exists($this->file))
        {

            echo "ERROR: Template file not found.";

        }

        $output = file_get_contents($this->file);

        foreach($this->values as $key => $value)
        {

            $find = "{".$key."}";
            $output = str_replace($find, $value, $output);

        }

        //$_GLOBALS["ran"] = true;
        return eval("?>".$output);

    }

}

?>

<br />
Thing-> {test}
```

Comment: `if(in_array('CLASS NAME', get_declared_classes())) {.....` is what you want.

Comment: @Darren Thank you so much, it worked perfectly, I did have to add an error_reporting(0); to get rid of another class has been called error, but it does what I need it to do. Please write that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Darren the only problem is, I had to put it at the top of the page, and it is repeating itself infinitely.

Comment: @M4TRIX, you should use `include_once` when including class files, it will take care rest of the things itself.

Comment: @ApulGupta I am trying to avoid those, I have put the class file inside the file I am trying to change. I have now changed my above code to match what I am currently having issues with.

Comment: Could you show how you include the files?

Comment: @Darren That is the only file I am using. I'm trying to avoid using more than this one file, when it says file_get_contents("test4.php"), the filename is test4.php, I am trying to make it call itself, but not call the class twice. That code above is the entire code on the page, from beginning to end, if this is not possible to do, please tell me, I have just been having some experimental issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need.

```
if(!in_array('NewTemplateHandler', get_declared_classes())) {
    $template = new NewTemplateHandler("test4.php");
    $template->output();
}
```

What you were doing before was this:

```
IF 
    (TRUE) 
THEN 
    START NEW TEMPLATE
ELSE
    ECHO "Else called"
```

What you wanted to do is check if it **is not** in the `get_declared_classes()` array.

Comment: That way the __construct function(or the class) is not being called. Should I give up on this idea?

Comment: If that is the code as you're using it, then you don't need the check at all? Just start the class and run the actions.

Comment: I am running an eval("?>".$output); so it is practically re-including the same file, and if it re-includes the same file it will re-declare the same class, and if it re-declares the same class I get a fatal error xD, can you see the issue I am having with this? It has left me stumped to the point where I am questioning it's use.